# slimScroll hidden on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm developing an application that uses the slimScroll jQuery plugin (http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll) to essentially add a nice overflow to div containers.

Everything works apart from a small, almost insignificant annoyance: when the page is loaded for the first time, the plugin is initiated on the div and automatically displays the scrollbar. After hovering in then out of the container, the scrollbar is hidden.

Is there any way to make the scrollbar start in a hidden state on page load?

The developer was asked this a number of times but I can't find a solution on the website.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code work for multiple elements that have same classes.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.inner').slimScroll({
//your options
opacity: 0
}).mouseover(function() {
$(this).next('.slimScrollBar').css('opacity', 0.4);
});
});
```

for such HTML code like this.

```
<div id='box'>
<div class='inner'>
some paragraph 
</div>
</div>
```

The result show here: https://jsfiddle.net/ATR616/4Lnr3fju/2/

Comment: Thanks ATR. I'll Mark this as the answer but there is a problem in the current code that doesn't work properly when there are multiple slimscroll containers with the same class (I am using a class instead of ID). Hovering over the first container 'activates' the scrollbar on the other containers.

Comment: Hi Rich, I'm forgot something to explain about changing code.

Comment: I've added $(this).next().css('opacity', 0.4); to the mouseover function to get the desired effect. Thanks again